# How to deploy Bot developed using Microsoft Bot framework SDK into other cloud platform other than azure

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have a fully developed simple functional chatbot (similar to weatherAPI Chabot) using Microsoft Bot framework SDK for ASP.Net core 6.0.
Can we deploy and publish this to any other cloud platform other than Azure like CloudFoudary and then integrate with channels like MS teams, Email... Almost all the resources I have looked so far
gives the info on publishing via Azure.

Any hint or direction would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Bot's project can be published to all platforms. This project is a web project, and publishing to CloudFoudary, local server IIS, or other cloud platforms is possible.

1. After the release is completed, all the configurations are the same as the web project, and the following page can be seen by visiting the URL at the end.

   [image]
2. Then we need tro set the messaging endpoint in azure portal.

   [image]

**Summary**

Azure Bot Service is a web project, all compilations and releases are the same as normal projects, and other steps can continue to follow the documentation.